# Gradle Spring Boot exclude logger error

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm getting the following error and I can't figure out why:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:179)
at ro.schedulerbot.app_starter.SchedulerBotApplication.main(SchedulerBotApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
```

Here is where I set **log4j** as the used logging framework:

```
dependencies {       
    //LOG4J
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.9.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.9.1'
}
```

Here is how my exclude method looks like:

```
ext.excludeDefaultLogger = {
exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"}
```

This is how I am adding the spring dependency:

```
dependencies {
//  SPRING
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.10.RELEASE', excludeDefaultLogger)}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Springboot still needs some kind of logging framework to run. If you excluded the default one, you need to replace it with something else.
Hope this helps: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8492

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it but I am actually using **log4j** as the logging framework. `//LOG4J
        compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.9.1'
        compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.9.1'`

Comment: I think "spring-boot-starter-logging" cannot be excluded as it's required to bridge log4j implementation with the internal interface:
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/default-logging.html